# How to test ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing, asp.net-web-api, automated-tests

I'm new to MVC and automated software testing. I tried searching google for Testing ASP.NET MVC applications, but couldn't reach to a good place to learn.

Would be glad if some one can direct me in the right direction on testing ASP.NET MVC project and WebAPI Projects.

Basically I'm looking for :

1. Web API Testing
2. View and Controller testing

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Found few articles on this, have listed them down below. Should help you get started.

- [Creating Unit Tests for ASP.NET MVC Applications (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs)
- [Unit Testing ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api)
- [Walkthrough: Using TDD with ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416511%28VS.98%29.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC: How to start Unit Testing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667370/ASP-NET-MVC-How-to-start-Unit-Testing)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've read all the articles pointed by you. I still have one confusion. How can we test data from database. For Example, Right now I'm working on Vehicle Tracking. So, for example, I have Distance report for a day. Which gives me total distance traveled for the day. Now for that, I need to have entries for a specified date in the db. So, How can i Populate DB first with test data? Or can there be a mock db?

Comment: @AshishCharan The database is just an implementation detail, so it should be abstracted away so as not to interfere with your tests. (Your thought of there being a mock database is on the right track.)

Comment: @Lilshieste Any Idea how to change that. I'm using EF and it takes actual db to work with.

Comment: @AshishCharan It can be pretty tough when you're using an ORM (like EF). Basically, instead of abstracting away the database you'll need to abstract away the EF. That is, resist the temptation to embed EF code throughout your codebase, even though it's really easy to do so. (It's "really easy" until you want to start unit testing your code.)